# how can i add color/ alignment/ background to my response.send("***some text***) or to the entire node.js doc

Tags: html, css, node.js, background

i am a **beginner** in node.js and am bit confused about how to add **text colors** or **background** and alignment etc..in my node.js document ..help me out with some solution so that i could get **sum =12 in red**

here i have provide you with some code ..suggest me some ways in its reference

```
                        **app.js**
const express= require("express");
const bodyparser =require("body-parser");
const app=express();
 
 app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

  app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile( __dirname+"/cal.html");
            
     });
  app.post("/",function(req,res)
  {
    var n1=Number(req.body.num1);
    var n2=Number(req.body.num2);
    var n=n1+n2;

    res.write("<h1>sum is" + n+"</h1>");
   res.send();


   }) 
   app.listen(2000,function()
   {
    console.log("server is running");
       });
```

> cal.html (html document)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>server </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="num1" value=number1>
    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="number3">
    <button type="submit" name="button">calculate</button>
    </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Hi Pallavi welcome at SO. As I see it, your problem is not node.js related. You just need to add CSS to your HTML with a `<style></style>` block inside `<head></head>` or create an external 'style.css' file doing the same. Add a class to `<h1 class="sum">sum is` and in the CSS `.sum { color: red }`

Comment: @Rene Van der Lende ...thank you so much...helped me a lot!!

Comment: Please 'accept' the answer so the issue can be closed. Further info: a good and very extensive site with tutorials, exercises, examples and references on HTML,CSS,JS,PHP, etc. is [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/), well worth your time!

Comment: I have used the method u suggested ...but it's really not working !!! Neither the color changed to red nor font size

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment on your question, simply add some proper CSS to your HTML document:

Notice`res.write('<h1 class="sum">sum is' + n+'</h1>');` in the javascript.

Added a `<h1>` in the HTML just to show what happens when you add the `<style></style>` block.

```js
/*
// DISABLED, here for demo only

const express= require("express");
const bodyparser =require("body-parser");
const app=express();
 
 app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

  app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile( __dirname+"/cal.html");
            
     });
  app.post("/",function(req,res)
  {
    var n1=Number(req.body.num1);
    var n2=Number(req.body.num2);
    var n=n1+n2;

    res.write('<h1 class="sum">sum is ' + n+'</h1>');
   res.send();


   }) 
   app.listen(2000,function()
   {
    console.log("server is running");
       });
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>server </title>

<style>
.sum { color: red }
</style>


</head>
<body>
    <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="num1" value=number1>
    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="number3">
    <button type="submit" name="button">calculate</button>
    </form>

    <!-- example output -->
    <h1 class="sum">sum is 99999</h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```